# Getting value from database table depending on field value

Tags: database, forms, wpdb, sql

I am using a plugin called formidable which is similar to Gravity Forms in terms of purpose.

I have two fields of interest. The first field loads up all the values in the `Town` column of my `wp_locations` table. Using the code below.

```
function frm_populate_posts_town($values, $field){
    if($field->id == 800){ //change 125 to the ID of the field to populate
    global $wpdb;
    $towns =$wpdb->get_results("SELECT Town FROM wp_locations");
    $values['options'] = array(); 
    foreach ($towns as $town) {

     $values['options'][$town->Town] = $town->Town;
     }

    }
    return $values;
}
```

The second field is a hidden field that automatically selects the value in the 'County' Column depending on the value of the first field. (btw `$_POST['item_meta'][802]` represents the hidden field

```
add_filter('frm_validate_field_entry', 'my_custom_validation_town', 8, 3);

function my_custom_validation_town($errors, $posted_field, $posted_value){
    if($posted_field->id == 802){ //change 25 to the ID of the hidden field
        $town_b = $_POST['item_meta'][800];//Gets the value from the first field
        global $wpdb;

        $query = "SELECT County FROM wp_locations WHERE Town = $town_b";
        $the_county = $wpdb->get_var($query);

          $_POST['item_meta'][802] = $the_county; 
    }
    return $errors;
}
```

The second does not work.

### EDIT

I found out that I need to use the action hook [frm_after_create_entry](http://formidablepro.com/knowledgebase/entry-management-create-update-delete/frm_after_create_entry/) and then add a Javascript in order to do 'Text calculations' which is one of the functions the plugin has.

Unfortunately I do not know how to add the SQL query as a variable using the value of `#field_800` e.g:

```
"SELECT County FROM wp_locations WHERE Town =`#field_800`"
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('#field_800').change(function(){

 var val1 = $("#field_800").val();//How can I add mySQL here 

$("#field_802").val(val1);
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? _Exactly where does this fail?

Comment: @s_ha_dum Hi, basically the function that I used for the second form is supposed to add a value to the field of choice (in this case 'item meta 802') when the form is submitted. I want the `$town_b` to select the value in the 'County' Column depending on the value of the 'town' chosen in the first field.it doesnt

Comment: @s_ha_dum I got it to achieve what I wanted to do by using the first function alone and Jquery. I changed `$values['options'][$town->Town] = $town->Town;` to `$values['options'][$town->Town] = $town->Town.'-'.$town->County;` ( I changed the SQL to `SELECT Town,County` ) and then use jquery String split to split the values into different fields. Considering what you told me about XY problems, I don't think it is right to put that as an answer, because its a workaround. Do you agree?

Comment: It is probably a workaround but you could still post the answer, and should.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that this is the wrong hook for what you are trying to do, or you are using it incorrectly.

A few notes:

You are passing unvalidated data into a query. Please don't do that. This...

```
$town_b = $_POST['item_meta'][800];//Gets the value from the first field
global $wpdb;

$query = "SELECT County FROM wp_locations WHERE Town = $town_b";
```

... is begging to be hacked. Any data in `$_POST['item_meta'][800]` hits the DB unfiltered. Very dangerous. Use `prepare`, at the very least.

```
$query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT County FROM wp_locations WHERE Town = %s",$town_b);
```

Second, you've hook into what is pretty obviously a field validation system but you are trying to set a `$_POST` value. [That is clearly not what it is meant for.](http://formidablepro.com/knowledgebase/frm_validate_field_entry/) So you are either too late or too early setting the value, or something. It is hard to tell with your two functions out of context the way they are. I can almost guarantee that you need to be using another hook though. Add some more detail and I will see about editing with a more specific answer.

Comment: hi I updated the question. I think i need to use one of their action hooks combined with [text calculations](http://formidablepro.com/knowledgebase/field-options-2/field-calculations/#kb-text-calculations) to achieve what i want. However I don't know how to put SQL into the script i added above.

Comment: You can't put SQL in the Javascript. You need to make a request via AJAX, but I'd suggest you back up, think about what you want to accomplish, and ask about that rather than ask how to do particular tasks. You've got an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), I'm pretty sure.

Comment: okay I understand where you are getting at. I thought that people in this site preferred to see that you made an effort to solve it yourself. 
All i want to do is use the value from a drop-down, populated by an SQL Table, to update another field with a value in another column and in the same row.

Comment: It is clear that you've made an effort :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I solved this by just using the first function and Jquery. I called up BOTH the Town and County in the first function as values inthe drop down list `Town-County` then i used Jquery string split to split the string using '-' as a separator and then put the values into two separate fields.

```
function frm_populate_posts_town($values, $field){
if($field->id == 800){ //change 125 to the ID of the field to populate
global $wpdb;
$towns =$wpdb->get_results("SELECT Town,County FROM wp_locations");
$values['options'] = array(); 
foreach ($towns as $town) {

 $values['options'][$town->Town] = $town->Town.'-'.$town->County;
 }

}
return $values;
}
```

I used this to split the dropdown list values into two separate fields.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('#field_hmm').change(function(){

var str = $("#field_hmm").val();
var substr = str.split('-');
var val1 = substr[0];
var val2 = substr[1];
$("#field_xhoxo1").val(val1);
  $("#field_xhoxo2").val(val2);
});
});
</script>
```